# Change navigation title for ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, abpersonviewcontroller

So I would like to change the title for the ABUnknownPersonViewController, and so I set it via code by setting the navigation item's title and titleView to put my custom label on it.

```
unknownPersonVC.title = @"title"
uknownPersonVC.titleView = myLabel;
```

This works OK.

In the UnknownPersonVC, there are cells "Create New Contact" and "Add to Existing Contact".

Tapping on them brings up screen to add a new contact or add to existing contact "modally".

How can I change the `color` of the `navigationItem.titleView` for those MVCs (or) set my label programmatically ?

Any ideas/hacks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for this answer...

```
 NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```